# How to distribute `.desktop` files and icons for a Python package?

Tags: python, setuptools, package-managers

I want to distribute a Python package with [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). Along with the package the following should be installed:

- a starter script
- a `.desktop` file to run the start script
- an icon for the `.desktop` file

I used the following `setup.py` file (full version is [here](https://gist.github.com/brutus/e4bdb1d2c1705558b2ff)):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  # ...
  data_files=[
    ('share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps', ['data/mypackage.svg']),
    ('share/applications', ['data/mypackage.desktop'])
  ],
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['startit=mypackage.cli:run']
  }
)
```

The starter skript trough `entry_points` works. But the `data_files` where put in an egg file and *not in the folders specified*, so they can't be accessed by the desktop shell.

To work around this, I used the following `setup.cfg` file:

```
[install]
single-version-externally-managed=1
record=install.txt
```

This does work, but it kinda feels to me more like a workaround.
Am I doing something wrong here?

What's the preferred way to handle this?